# Neural Network optimization for image classification in keras/tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, image-classification

I am writing a program for clasifying images into two categories: "Wires" and "non-Wires". I have hand-labeled around 5000 microscope images, examples:

#### non-wire

[image]

#### wire

[image]

The neural network I am using is adapted from "Deep Learning with Python", chapter about convolutional networks (I don't think convolutional networks are neccesary here because there are no obvious hierarchies; Dense networks should be more suitable):

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu',input_shape=(200,200,3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

However, test accuracy after 10 epochs of training does not go over 92% when playing around with the paramters of the network. Training images contain about 1/3 wires, 2/3 non-wires. My question: Do you see any obvious mistakes in this neural network design that inhibits accuracy, or do you think I am limited by the image quality? I have about 4000 train and 1000 test images.

Comment: what is the size of the images. From what I saw it looks like the number of pixels in the region of interest is small compared to the total number of pixels in the image. Disagree about use of a convolutional network but then your image is to small to tell much.

Comment: Did you inspect the images that are mis-classified? I too disagree about the statement that a CNN is not suitable. Conv layers provide some location-invariance and I believe you want that in this use-case.

Comment: Image size is 200x200x3. Concerning location invarience: The images are centered around possible wires. But yeah, I will try convnets again - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You might get some improvement by trying to handle the class imbalance using a weights dictionary. If the label of non wire is 0 and the label for wire is 1 then the weight dictionary would be

```
weight_dict= { 0:.5, 1:1}
```

in model.fit set

```
 class_weight=weight_dict .
```

Without seeing the results of training (training loss and validation loss) can't tell what else to do. If you are over fitting try adding some dropout layers. Also recommend you try using an adjustable learning using the keras callback ReduceLROnPlateau, and early stopping using the keras callback EarlyStopping. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/) Set each callback to monitor validation loss. My suggested code is shown below:

```
reduce_lr=tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(
          monitor="val_loss",factor=0.5, patience=2, verbose=1)
e_stop=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping( monitor="val_loss", patience=5, 
          verbose=0,  restore_best_weights=True)
callbacks=[reduce_lr, e_stop]
```

In model.fit include

```
callbacks=callbacks
```

If you want to give a convolutional network a try I recommend transfer learning using the Mobilenetmodel. Documentation for that is [here.](https://keras.io/api/applications/mobilenet/). My recommend code for that is below:

```
base_model=tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet( include_top=False, 
          input_shape=(200,200,3) pooling='max', weights='imagenet',dropout=.4) 
x=base_model.output
x=keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001 )(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x=Dropout(rate=.3, seed=123)(x) 
output=Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)
model=Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)
model.compile(Adamax(lr=.001),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics= 
              ['accuracy'] )
```

In model.fit include the callbacks as shown above.

Comment: Let me know if it helps